# How to send Back Button and Home Button Commands with Screen Monitor-Droid Explorer 0.9.0.4

Tags: droid-explorer

The Droid Explorer version 0.9.0.4 Screen Monitor feature provides the ability to use a mouse to select and use applications on Android devices, but the back button and home button are not available on the screen. An application is available for download from Google Play to provide this function.

Is it possible to send back button and home button commands with Screen Monitor without downloading an application?

Answer (score 0):

About keyboard shortcut <kbd>Home</kbd> 
button input can be send using  <kbd>Esc</kbd> 
 key located at the top left corner of qwerty keyboard...
Still looking for back button shortcut.